# Display json api data in html list

Tags: php, jquery, json, api, jsonp

I have a json API key & I am trying to convert the json data to display in unordered list in HTML or php.

This is the API key I have : http://kippamp.uservoice.com/api/v1/forums/1/suggestions.json?client=qikbghkQYRolFTMvEXg

I am able to parse the raw json data using the below code :

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://kippamp.uservoice.com/api/v1/forums/1/suggestions.json?client=qikbghkQYRolFTMvEXg',
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#jsonp-results').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
       alert(e.message);
    }
});
</script>
```

but not able to parse the data to list in a formatted way.

Can someone here help me please.

Regards.

Comment: create for loop and insert data in <li>data</li>..

Comment: yogesh can you please able to expalin the code in order to create the loop.
I am trying to do that but of no use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just render your results in the loop. For example appending them into `ul` container:

```
success: function (data) {
    var $ul = $('#results');
    $.each(data.suggestions, function(i, el) {
       $ul.append('<li>' + el.formatted_text + '</li>');
    });
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvBE3/

You just need to decide what data you need to present and what template you should use:

```
var row =
    '<li>' + 
        '<h2>' + el.title + '</h2>' +
        '<div>' + el.formatted_text + '</div>'+
    '</li>';
$ul.append(row);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvBE3/3/

Comment: can you tell me one more thing please...
can i control the list count e.g. if i just need to show 4 or 5 items?

Comment: Just checked their API. You can control number of returned results with `per_page` parameter. E.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/zvBE3/4/

Answer (score 1):

Ajax request returns an object, you have to loop over `data.suggestions` to create your list.
Something like:

```
$.each(data.suggestions, function(id, suggestion) {
    $('ul.mylist').append($('<li>'+suggestion.title+'</li>'));
});
```